# Angular 5 - How to Consume Provider's Key Declared Using InjectionToken on a Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm learning various method on how we can implement `Dependency Injection` on Angular 5. It was known that Angular 5 have **3 different methods** of how we can declare **provider's key / token** when declaring a dependency.

**First,** using **Class** (the easiest and most common way), e.g:

```
// in app.module.ts
import { HotMail } from './hot-mail';
...
...
...
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HotMail,
      useClass: HotMail
    }
  ],
})
...
...
```

and then

```
// in email.component.ts
import { HotMail } from './hot-mail';
...
...
export class EmailComponent {
  ...
  constructor(private emailService: HotMail) { }
  ...
}
```

**Second,** using **String** (not recommended since can cause name collision), e.g:

```
// in app.module.ts
import { HotMail } from './hot-mail';
...
...
...
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'EMS', // Here we are using string
      useClass: HotMail
    }
  ],
})
...
...
```

and then

```
// in email.component.ts
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
// Here we don't need to import HotMail
...
...
export class EmailComponent {
  ...
  constructor(@Inject('EMS') private emailService) { }
  ...
}
```

**Third,** using **InjectionToken** (preferable than the second method), e.g:

```
// in app.module.ts
import { HotMail } from './hot-mail';
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
...
...
...
const AnyName = new InjectionToken<HotMail>('Any Message');
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AnyName,
      useClass: HotMail
    }
  ],
})
...
...
```

and then, **here is the problem,** I could not find a way how we can consume a token declared using `InjectionToken`, when I run `ng serve` it always return an error message, for example when i do following:

```
// in email.component.ts
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
// Here we don't need to import HotMail
...
...
export class EmailComponent {
  ...
  constructor(@Inject(AnyName) private emailService) { }
  ...
}
```

It always return

```
ERROR in ../../../email.component.ts: Cannot find name 'AnyName'
```

**How to fix this problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import that token into your component and then inject it. In a separate file you can have this token as exported member

```
export const AnyName = new InjectionToken<HotMail>('Any Message');
```

Then import it into the files you want to use it.

Comment: Is there any way we can consume the token without having to create separate file (i.e `AnyName` declared on `app.module.ts`)? I know if i import `app.module.ts` on `email.component.ts` it will cause circular dependency error.

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is a variable, so if you want to work with it, you need to import it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export it like you would anything else

```
export const AnyName = new InjectionToken<HotMail>('Any Message');
```

and naturally import it like you would anything else

```
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {AnyName} from './m';

export default class {
  constructor(@Inject(AnyName) a) {...}
}
```